# Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 Project Options not working

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

I just created new console application project by `Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2` . But Project Options(Alt+P) not working and `Error: Access violation at address 0012F64B`. Write of address 0012F64B. How to fix this problem.

Comment: Is it the IDE (Dev-C++) that crashes, or your program? If it's your program then you have two different problems that should be asked in two different questions.

Comment: Dev-C++ is not a good IDE, recomendation: move to CodeBlocks or Visual Studio?

Comment: Or Clion. Nobody ever suggesting Clion.

Comment: @DavidHaim Why Dev-C++ is not good ?

Comment: for many reasons. first of all, it have never being stable, every version has its bugs. second of all, you don't get important features like code completion/intellisense. third of all, the error messages you get in compile time are ugly as hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Dev-C++ problem , update it . [Details](http://sourceforge.net/p/orwelldevcpp/tickets/82/)